# How to Mock a method with dynamic type in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, mocking, moq

Hi I've a method in an interface

```
dynamic SendCancelRequest(dynamic request, string contentType = "application/json");
```

I want to mock it, I am using moq

```
var inputModel = new
{
   id = consumerId,
   userip = getUserIp(),
   Source = "x-source"
};
var result = new
{
   Name = "Acknowledge"
};

_mock.Setup(c => c.SendCancelRequest(inputmodel,"application/json")).Returns(result);
```

When I debug the actual line, I see the value that I want to return is always null.

```
dynamic message = MyRepository.SendCancelRequest(inputModel);
```

The value of message is null. Also the value of input model also not reflected, rightnow I just need the value of message 
What am I missing how should I fix it ?

Comment: Show the method under test. Most probably the parameters provided in the test do not match what was setup and thus the mocked method wont perform as expected.

Comment: Thanks Nikosi, I later figured out.
if I write  _mock.Setup(c => c.SendCancelRequest(It.IsAny<dynamic>,"application/json")).Returns(result); instead of _mock.Setup(c => c.SendCancelRequest(inputmodel,"application/json")).Returns(result);
it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
_mock.Setup(c => c.SendCancelRequest(inputmodel,"application/json")).Returns(result);
```

doesn't work but the code below works:

```
_mock.Setup(c => c.SendCancelRequest(It.IsAny<object>(),"application/json")).Returns(result);
```